# Why does my git bash always start at master branch?

Tags: bash, git

I have a Windows PC with git installed. Whenever I start git bash, it always stand at `/c/Users/_user` with `master` branch as below:

```
NativeKiwi@nkiwi MINGW64 ~ (master)
```

I think it should look like this:

```
NativeKiwi@nkiwi MINGW64 ~
```

I had a look at people around, found out that they don't have `(master)` at their first start using git bash. I checked git repo at where I stand with `git remote -v` but there is nothing.

Comment: I think this means `/c/Users/_user` is a git repository. If `git remote -v` doesn't return an error, that would be confirmation of this. Try `git status` to see what's going on. If you really don't want this to be a git repository anymore, you should be able to just delete the `.git` directory.

Comment: @smarx I forgot to check it with `git status` at first :) It do show me a list of untracked files. And I think that is the consequence of my first try with git at the wrong location :D It solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The string shown in your prompt depends on your `PS1` environment variable.
Please check your .bash_profile or .bashrc　for the configuration of PS1 environment variable.

Comment: I had checked the environment variable, no `PS1` was set. And there was no `.bash_profile` as well as `.bashrc` file at that starting location. I think @smarx 's answer solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (due to running `git init`) in the wrong directory and fixed it by running `rm -rf .git` in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing master because you created a git repository at the current path using the `git init` command. Always create git repositories in the folders containing project files. Consider running `rm -rf .git` command.